# Change pager template

Tags: magento-1, pagination, toolbar, pager

I am trying to include a different pager for the bottom toolbar. For this I have changed the template used by the bottom toolbar:

```
<?php echo $this->getToolbarBlock()->setTemplate('catalog/product/list/toolbar-bottom.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

How can I change the template used for `<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml() ?>` within `toolbar-bottom.phtml`?

Comment: you need to change template template/page/html/pager.phtml

Comment: but it will be for all pager. if you want for particular toolbar only you need to change it.

Answer (score 0):

`getPagerHtml()` not use any template file. This is a function of `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar` Class.

Comment: getPagerHtml() use template page/html/pager.phtml

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```php
/* @var $toolbar \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar */
// set correct template to related block
$toolbar->getChildBlock('product_list_toolbar_pager')->setTemplate('path/to/pager_template.phtml');
// render pager
echo $toolbar->getPagerHtml();
```